# LinkedHashSet Documentation Ambiguity: Re-insert

Tags: java, linkedhashset

The java documentation for [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) states this:

*Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the set. (An element e is reinserted into a set s if s.add(e) is invoked when s.contains(e) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)*

For a recent project I decided to use one to hold a set of data tokens in a client-server communication for display to users in some list view widget. The idea being that I'd be able to cheaply re-insert elements with updated data and the user wouldn't be surprised because the order wouldn't change.

Obviously that's not the case, using Oracle JRE 1.7.0_55-b13 it operates like any other [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29), as this short test program shows:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

import static java.util.Arrays.deepToString;

public class LhsStack 
{
    public static class T 
    {
        public T ( int id ) { this.id = id; }

        public final Integer id;
        public String value;

        @Override
        public int hashCode () { return id.hashCode (); }

        @Override
        public boolean equals ( Object obj ) 
        { 
            return obj instanceof T && id.equals ( ((T)obj).id ); 
        }

        @Override
        public String toString () { return id + " => " + value; }
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        LinkedHashSet < T > set = new LinkedHashSet <> ();

        T a = new T ( 1 ),
          b = new T ( 1 ),
          c = new T ( 2 ),
          d = new T ( 3 );

        a.value = "Hello, World";
        b.value = "World, Hello";
        c.value = "Foo";
        d.value = "Bar"; 

        System.out.println ( "a == b: " + a.equals ( b ) );

        if ( set.add ( a ) ) {
            System.out.println ( "Inserted: " + a.value );
        }

        System.out.println ( "set.contains ( a ): " + set.contains ( a ) );
        System.out.println ( "set.contains ( b ): " + set.contains ( b ) );

        set.add ( c ); set.add ( d );

        System.out.println ( "Elements: " + set.size () );
        System.out.println ( deepToString ( set.toArray () ) );

        if ( set.add ( b ) ) {
            System.out.println ( "Re-Inserted: " + b.value );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println ( "Removing and Adding: " + b.value );
            set.remove ( b );
            set.add ( b );
        }

        System.out.println ( "Elements: " + set.size () );
        System.out.println ( deepToString ( set.toArray () ) );
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
a == b: true
Inserted: Hello, World
set.contains ( a ): true
set.contains ( b ): true
Elements: 3
[1 => Hello, World, 2 => Foo, 3 => Bar]
Removing and Adding: World, Hello
Elements: 3
[2 => Foo, 3 => Bar, 1 => World, Hello]
```

My question therefore is, since element *b* is not re-inserted into the set (i.e. it has to be removed, then re-added to update its value), what is the significance of the comment in the java documentation?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, `linkedHashSet.add(elementToAdd)` makes `elementToAdd` be the last element of `linkedHashSet`. The significance of the comment in the Javadoc is that if `elementToAdd` already appears inside `linkedHashSet`, then `linkedHashSet.add(elementToAdd)` will just leave it in place (and will not move it to the end).

For what you're trying to do, you're better off with a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, T>`. You can then iterate over its `values()` to get your `T` instances in iteration order, with the ability to update mappings. (If you want, you can then wrap `LinkedHashMap<Integer, T>` in some sort of container object that, instead of offering `put(Integer, T)`, instead offers an `add(T)` that handles the key-mapping behind the scenes. In fact, it should be very straightforward to extend `AbstractSet<T>` to create a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, T>`-based implementation of `Set<T>`.)

---

**Edit for updated question:** Ah, O.K., sorry, I now understand your confusion better. The above is an explanation of the purpose of the first sentence ("Note that insertion order is *not* affected if an element is *re-inserted* into the set"); I did not realize that you were misunderstanding the second sentence ("An element `e` is reinserted into a set `s` if `s.add(e)` is invoked when `s.contains(e)` would return `true` immediately prior to the invocation.")

So, let me explain. The second sentence is merely a *definition* of the term "reinserted"; it's not describing any behavior. The sentence is not saying that a `LinkedHashSet` will do anything called "reinsertion" if you call its `add` method with an element it already contains; rather, the sentence saying that if you call its `add` method with an element it already contains, then this call is called "reinsertion". The (non-)effect of reinsertion is what's explained in the first sentence, namely, that it won't move the element to the end.

`LinkedHashSet.add` still obeys the requirements of `Set.add`, which specifies that "Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present (optional operation). [...]  If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns `false`."

There are some cases of JDK classes that do not obey the requirements of the interfaces they claim to implement, but when that happens, it will be called out as a boldface warning, not just tucked away inside a parenthetical note and never mentioned again. See [the Javadoc of `IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) for an example of this.

Comment: LinkedHashMap is indeed what I used in the end. In reply to your first paragraph-that's the behaviour I was expecting, except that the operation doesn't perform the re-insert the element as shown in my test program, i.e. the last line reads "Hello, World" instead of "World, Hello".

Comment: @arfbtwn: I see. When you wrote "what is the significance of the comment", I thought you were asking about the *purpose* of the *first* sentence (since it was explaining what already seemed obvious to you); I didn't realize you were asking about the *meaning* of the *second* sentence. I've updated my answer now; please let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Great, sorry it wasn't entirely clear first time round. It's weird that they felt the need to mention it in the documentation because if you call add with an object already stored in a `HashSet` then the behaviour is the same, i.e. the set is not modified so obviously the order remains the same too. Thanks for clarifying what they meant. :)

Comment: @arfbtwn: "It's weird that they felt the need to mention it in the documentation [...]": I agree that it seems obvious, but if it *weren't* mentioned, I could easily imagine someone not thinking about this case, and wrongly assuming that `lhs.add("x")` guarantees that the last element will be `"x"`. (After all, this is a basic utility class with many possible applications. Someone thinking to use it for one purpose may not think about situations where its implementation doesn't quite match that purpose.)